# Вывод максимального числа в массиве

Tags: javascript, массивы

Вывожу максимальное число функцией.

```js
var myArray = [0, 1, 9, 4, 3, 2, 8, 6];
var result = myArray[0];

function maxResult(data) {
  for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    if (data[i] > data[0]) {
      data[0] = data[i];
      console.log(data[0]);
    }
  }
}
maxResult(myArray);
```

В результате в console я получаю результат 1 и 9. Не могу понять в чем проблема.

Прошу тапками не бросаться, пока только еще изучаю javascript.

Спасибо за ответы. Вопрос закрыт.

Comment: потому что Вы в цикле выполняете `console.log()`. 1 > 0, 9>1, дальше все числа меньше. вынесите `console.log()` за цикл.

Comment: обрати внимание. что ты портишь исходный массив, меняя его первое значение на максимальное

Comment: Да, я это заметила. Уже исправила.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Результат нужно выводить после цикла, т.к. в цикле вы выводите только промежуточные результаты

Answer (score 1):

Вы выводили в консоль в теле цикла, надо после

```js
var myArray = [0, 1, 9, 4, 3, 2, 8, 6];
var result = myArray[0];

function maxResult(data) {
  for (i = 0; i < data.length; i++) {
    if (data[i] > data[0]) {
      data[0] = data[i];
    }
  }
 console.log(data[0]);
}

maxResult(myArray);
```

Comment: @nick_n_a в этом случае на вопрос бы не было ответа